# Doctrine error "Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens"

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony1, doctrine, symfony-1.4

I'm building a Symfony 1.4.20 application and I wrote this code:

```
public function getListForAdmin() {
    $user = sfContext::getInstance()->getUser();
    $q = $this->createQuery('g');

    if ($user->hasCredential('can_admin_full')) {
        $q->addWhere('g.name IN (?)', array('Administradores Monitor', 'Monitor'));
    } else if ($user->hasCredential('can_admin')) {
        $q->addWhere('g.name IN (?)', array('Monitor'));
    }

    return $q;
}
```

Seeing in Symfony logs the result query is as follow:

```
SELECT s.id AS s__id, s.name AS s__name, s.description AS s__description, s.created_at AS s__created_at, s.updated_at AS s__updated_at 
      FROM sf_guard_group s 
      WHERE (s.name IN ('Administradores Monitor'))
```

I run the query in phpMyAdmin and all is fine meaning query doesn't have any problem but in Symfony with Doctrine I get this error:

> SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables 
>   does not match number of tokens

Why? What's wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that problem in this rows:

```
 $q->addWhere('g.name IN (?)', array('Administradores Monitor', 'Monitor'));
```

and

```
 $q->addWhere('g.name IN (?)', array('Monitor'));
```

**It should be:**

```
$q->whereIn('g.name', array('Administradores Monitor', 'Monitor'));
```

**and**

```
$q->whereIn('g.name', array('Monitor'));
```

**UPDATE: edit answer**

Comment: @denys821 I change the code to your suggestion but get this error `Fatal error: Call to undefined method Doctrine_Query::addWhereIn() in /var/www/html/monitor/lib/model/doctrine/sfDoctrineGuardPlugin/sfGuardGroupTable.class.php on line 28`

Comment: @deny821 don't worry after some research I found the solution or think to. `addWhereIn` doesn't exists in Doctrine(see [here](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine1/en/latest/en/manual/dql-doctrine-query-language.html)), instead I use `whereIn` and then the code works, anyway thanks and I'll give you the points for help me and point me in the right direction

Comment: @Reynier Sorry, I was inattentive, and I wrote answer with my memory :(